# How do I split up a string of binary to compare each digit?

Tags: c++, binary, xor

I have to take a binary string of any length, stuff the string until it can be split into groups of 3. Say I have a string of 5, I add a 0 to the right end of it to make it a string of 6, then split them into 3 and compare the same digit with the XOR operator. I know how to stuff the binary string with 0's until it's able to be split by 3 but I don't know how to split it by three and compare the digits. Here is the code I have for stuffing it with 0's.

```
string binary;
cin >> binary;


while(binary.length() < 6){
    binary = "0" + binary;
}


while(binary.length()%3 != 0){
    binary = "0" + binary;
}


int size = binary.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate over the string using `for-loop` and create new strings adding it to the dynamic array then you can iterate over the dynamic array

```
string *a = new string[ binary.length() ];

for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length() - 3; i +=3 )
{
    a[i/3] = binary.substr(i, 3);
}

//now you have array of 3 length splitted parts

delete[] a;
```

---

EDIT

If you don't need to keep the triples of substrings to xor every first, second and third element of substring just use

```
//to convert char to int I'm subtracting 48 from its ASCII
int xors[3] = { (int)binary[0] - 48, (int)binary[3] - 48, (int)binary[2] - 48, };

for(int i = 3; i <= binary.length() - 3; i +=3 )
{
    xors[0] ^= (int)binary[i] - 48;
    xors[1] ^= (int)binary[i+1] - 48;
    xors[2] ^= (int)binary[i+2] - 48;
}
```

IF you want to keep triples iterate use code above and iterate over it handling it like here

Comment: why didn't you use a `std::vector`?

Comment: sure you can - this is just one of way

Comment: How do use this to compare a binary number? say it ends up being 010001, it slits up into 010 001, and I compare the first digit of the first term, to the first of the second using the XOR operator.

Comment: "I have to take a binary string of any length ..." but your algorithm assumes there's at least three elements in the string.

Comment: because your part guarantees that there are at least 6 chars in the string `while(binary.length() < 6){
    binary = "0" + binary;
}` of course in other situation you have to make some condition also

Answer (score 0):

why convert to integer? Can do it all with `std::string` ;-)
Complete runnable program. Only requirement is that the initial string `digits` is 3 long. Any pre-processing (e.g. adding of padding '0's) is left out.

The program easily adapts to grouping different number of bits by just changing the value of `3` to the desired grouping length (and assuring the input is at least that long).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Assume string has been made at least six long; although we settle for 3
    string            digits("000111101");
    string::iterator  ptr = next(digits.begin(), 3);
    // copy first N digits into our accumulators
    string            xors(digits.begin(), ptr);
    string::size_type idx = 0;

    // Aggregate-xor the remaining digits
    while( ptr!=digits.end() ) {
        xors[ idx ] = (xors[idx]!=*ptr) ? '1' : '0';
        ptr++, idx = (idx + 1) % xors.size();
    }

    cout << "Final xor'ed bits: " << xors << endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Final xor'ed bits: 010
```